Concerns About Schengen Visa Approval for Freelance Developers Without Traditional Employment Proof
My wife and I, both freelance developers from India, are planning to travel to Belgium on a tourist visa.
Also we have a relative in Belgium who could provide us a simple invitation letter and ID proof for stay at their house.
Since we work independently, we don’t have traditional employment proof, only direct client payments in our accounts.
Could this be a concern or obstacle in obtaining a Schengen visa?

You should have invoices, contracts, tax returns… but it would probably be easier if you set up a company with its own accounts and payments from the company to you (with relevant justification, I.e. salary or dividends…). But having a job that is easily transposable in Belgium + relatives there means you need some iron-clad proof of ties to your country…

Traditional seems odd. We understand what do you mean, but do you think doctors, architects, lawyers ever had a traditional employment proof? (or businessman). You are just a normal independent worker. -- some people create own company because taxes, insurances, social benefits, etc. to balance uncertainty, but it is a complex topic, not for this site).
